# Automatically apply puppet catalog upon login to client node

Tags: puppet

I tried to execute shell script automatically when a user logins to a Puppet client node. I need to trigger `puppet agent --test` on a puppet client when a user logins to it.

Comment: What is, exactly, your question? Are you getting any error? What have you tried?

Comment: I have shell script which i am able to execute through manifests on puppet client by "puppet agent -t ". Now I need to execute  "puppet agent -t" command automatically when any user login to puppet client machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to execute "puppet agent -t" command automatically when any user login to puppet client machine

That is going to be problematic, as `puppet` needs to run as root.

You can add

`sudo puppet agent -t`

to your `/etc/profile` , and also add

`ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: puppet`

to your `/etc/sudoers` file.

But this is NOT something I would recommend.

Comment: thank you very much i solved it by putting the puppet agent -t in /etc/bashrc

Comment: @Asim if it solved your problem, remember to accept the answer.